# Python: Beginning problems

Tags: python

ok so basically i very new to programming and have no idea how to go about these problems
help if you will ^^

1. Numerologists claim to be able to determine a person’s character traits based on the “numeric value” of a name. The value of a name is determined by summing up the values of the letters of the name, where ‘a’ is 1, ‘b’ is 2, ‘c’ is 3 etc., up to ‘z’ being 26. For example, the name “Zelle” would have the value 26 + 5 + 12 + 12 + 5 = 60 (which happens to be a very suspicious
   number, by the way). Write a program that calculates the numeric value of a single name provided as input.
2. Word count. A common utility on Unix/Linux systems is a small program called “wc”. This program counts the number of lines, words (strings of characters separated by blanks, tabs, or new lines), and characters in a file. Write your own version of this program. The program should accept a file name as input and then print three numbers showing the count of lines, words, and characters in the file.

Comment: Sniff sniff..smells like an homework to me :).

Comment: Can you specify your problems? I am sure you must have *some* thoughts about it...

Comment: Two problems from chapter four of Python programming: an introduction to computer science By John M. Zelle.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you have tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: haha ok
so the first problem:
ive defined the variables a-z (a=A=1, etc.) but am stuck as to how to add the letters of an input of a name written out in full and show the numeric value
the only thing i can think of is asking for the name to be typed out letter by letter and showing the sum every time (i havent even tried this yet)
like i said...very new to programming...and posting for help too
sorry if this annoyed anyone

Answer (score 4):

I won't give you an answer, I want to help you:

Read the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/)!

What you ask for is pretty basic and should be perfectly covered by the tutorial, especially read about [strings](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) and [reading files](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

*Disclaimer: @Charles Beattie I am ok with a downvote ;) If anyone considers this not to be a valid answer I'll put it as comment, just say so.*

Comment: I agree with you! Charles, do not scary others if their answer gives hints only, and not a complete solution. +1 for tutorial links.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you a full answer as well :)

I like [Google's Python tutorial](http://code.google.com/intl/xx-bork/edu/languages/google-python-class/). In addition to small easy written tutorials, it has video lectures (which also covers strings and reading files). At the end of each topic, you can do simple exercises (provided on the tutorial page).

Answer (score 0):

Questions like these should not be asked if they come from a book! usually the auther gives plenty of tips! However, after a year i think it's ok for you too see an approach that some would use.

*Question 1*

```
def answer1(name, value=0):
    for char in name:
        value += int(char, 36) - 9                     
    print value

answer1(raw_input("give your name: ").lower())
```

*Question 2*

```
# place your python script in the textfile location or rewrite the path
file_all    = open('C:\\somefile.txt')
value_lines = 0
value_words = 0
value_chars = 0

for lines in file_all:
    value_lines += 1
    for words in lines.split():
        value_words += 1
        for chars in words:
            value_chars += 1
print value_lines, '\n', value_words, '\n', value_chars
```

this is the general idea you would want to use, good luck with it!

Answer (score 0):

```
def WordCalc():
       name = raw_input("Enter value: ")   
       value = 0
       for char in name:
           value += int(char, 36) - 9

       print value
       print name

WordCalc()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider adding a few words to help explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
    value = 0
    name = name.replace(" ", "")

    for char in name:
         value += int(char, 36) - 9

    print value
    print name

main()
```

> If you have problem about space inside string you can use this code